# Return only one post format in index.php

Tags: loop, images, gallery, post-formats

I'm trying to customize index.php of my theme in order to return/display only one post format (images in this case), and hide all the rest(aside, video, link...).
I tried to implement this code in my index page, but I get error.
I Hope someone can help.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'post-format-image' ),
        )
    )
);
```

Code of index.php

```
<div class="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $total_post_count = wp_count_posts();
        $published_post_count = $total_post_count->publish;
        $total_pages = ceil( $published_post_count / $posts_per_page );


        if ( "1" < $paged ) : ?>

            <div class="page-title">

                <h4><?php printf( __('Page %s of %s', 'fukasawa'), $paged, $wp_query->max_num_pages ); ?></h4>

            </div> <!-- /page-title -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="posts" id="posts">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- /posts -->
```

Comment: It's using wordpress core post format. You can change default post format from `Setting> writing > Default Post Format`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. 
All I need to add is the following line of code `query_posts( $args );`
The result will be something like this:

```
<div class="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $total_post_count = wp_count_posts();
        $published_post_count = $total_post_count->publish;
        $total_pages = ceil( $published_post_count / $posts_per_page );


        if ( "1" < $paged ) : ?>

            <div class="page-title">

                <h4><?php printf( __('Page %s of %s', 'fukasawa'), $paged, $wp_query->max_num_pages ); ?></h4>

            </div> <!-- /page-title -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
                $args = array(
                'post_type'=> 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'post-format-image' ),

                )
            )
        );
                query_posts( $args );
    ?>

        <div class="posts" id="posts">

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div> <!-- /posts -->
```